# How do I std::getline into a template type?

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, stdstring

```
template <typename T>
T getUserInput(std::string prompt = "")
{
    T input;
    std::cout << prompt;
    if (std::is_same<T, std::string>::value)
    {
        std::getline(std::cin, input);
    }
    else
    {
        std::cin >> input;
        std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
    }
    return input;
}
```

I'm trying to use getline instead of cin when the type is a string (in order to include whitespace), however I get a bunch of errors saying that I didn't provide enough arguments for std::getline. I've also tried to do this:

```
    if (std::is_same<T, std::string>::value)
    {
        std::string sInput = "";
        std::getline(std::cin, sInput);
        return sInput;
    }
```

But I get an error saying I can't convert from 'std::string' to 'T'. How can I make it so it treats T as std::string?

**Edit:** Here's how I'm calling it:

```
int main()
{
    int x = getUserInput<int>("Please type a number: ");
    std::cout << x << '\n';
    std::string test = getUserInput<std::string>("Please type a string: ");
    std::cout << test << '\n';
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you call the function with some `T` other than `std::string`, then the `getline` code will not compile, since all the code needs to be compiled regardless of whether the branch is taken, or not.

To avoid compiling the branch with the `getline` when not needed, you can use `if constexpr`, like this:

```
if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, std::string>)
{
    std::getline(std::cin, input);
}
else
{
    std::cin >> input;
}
```

Here's a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/JjxXMM).

Comment: Note that `if constexpr` was introduced in C++17, the same version that introduced the `std::is_same_v` helper, so you can also use this instead: `if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, std::string>)`

Answer (score 1):

Another option besides `if constexpr` (which there is nothing wrong with) is function overloading and/or specialization, e.g.:

```
// default version if not specialized
template<typename T>
T doUserInput()
{
    T input;
    std::cin >> input;
    std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
    return input;
}        

template<>
std::string doUserInput() 
{
    std::string s;
    std::getline(std::cin, s);
    return s;
}

template <typename T>
T getUserInput(std::string prompt = "")
{
    std::cout << prompt;
    return doUserInput<T>();
}
```

Comment: In my view there's a lot wrong with `if constexpr`. Writing a single function that has two different branches based on a type is no better than writing a single function that has two different branches chosen by `#ifdef`. We reject such uses of the preprocessor because they tend to produce unusable code, we should reject this use of `if constexpr` as well. So there! +1.